# R - format of a date

Tags: r, formatting, format

I am facing an issue with formatting of date and cannot find a solution. Here is the code - the second date becomes not the format like I want to.

```
date1
#[1] "01. Nov 11"

ndate1 <- as.Date(date1, "%d. %B %y")
ndate1
#[1] "2011-11-01"

date2
#[1] "26-May-13"

ndate2 <- as.Date(date2, "%d-%B-%y")
ndate2
#[1] NA
```

Comment: If the answers have solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer that you found most useful by [clicking on the tick on the left](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to an incompatibility with the locale settings. If the output of `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` does not correspond to an English setting, like `"en_US.UTF-8"` or `"en_GB.UTF-8"`, the abbreviation "May" (which, coincidentally, is not even an abbreviation in this case) is not recognized in most (all?) other settings. In contrast, "Nov" is a valid abbreviation for the month of November in several languages. This might explain why the first case with `date1` does not cause trouble.

We could try this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
date2 <- "26-May-13"
ndate2 <- as.Date(date2, "%d-%b-%y")
ndate2
#[1] "2013-05-26"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the complete or abbreviated month names in your locale using the example on the ?Constants page:

```
 format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b")
```

Per `?strptime` on input you can use either `"%B"` or `"%b"` for either abbreviated or complete names.